How to Run a Dash App Without Crashing During Edits?
I am new to dash and currently working to understand it. I have been able to get my first app up and running, but every time I edit it the server crashes due to a syntax error. I've worked with Flask before and this has never been an issue (typically it allows me to keep editing while still maintaining the server). My code is below.
# Import Packages
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dash_table, dcc
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = [
    html.H1("Hello, World!")
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


The default refresh is 3 seconds so if you are modifying your code and have a syntax error durning that refresh, app.py will finish with code 1. Check out the documentation on app.run

This is due to a feature called "Hot Reloading". Per the Dash documentation:

Code Reloading & Hot Reloading
By default, Dash includes Code Reloading & Hot Reloading. This means that Dash will automatically refresh your browser when you make a change in your Python or CSS code.

You can control this behavior:

Hot reloading is configurable through a set of parameters: use_reloader, dev_tools_hot_reload, and the dev_tools_hot_reload_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_watch_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_max_retry

Source: Dash Dev Tools Documentation
